# Where can I ask about performance of different tools and the fittest for my usecase?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a very specific use case. I need to know the performance of four different implementation approaches and get recommendation on the best one for the given case study.

On which Stack Exchange site can I ask this question? Is it off-topic for Stack Overflow?

The question:

> I am going to make an Android app, I care the most about speed. The
> app needs a database. There are a few entities. The problem is the
> many-to-many tables. there are A LOT of m-m relationships between
> entities. Each table will hold tons of rows, think +10K
>
> Now how to approach this?
>
> - local SQLite: the problem is the join statements. writing them is going to be a pain. Also, should I use an ORM? or will the join tables make it harder?
> - Firebase: is it fast enough? can it handle these relationships to begin with? using it will assure constant backup which is something I want
> - custom REST API: add all the heavy lifting in the remote server, problem is it will need an active internet connection. Plus I think
>   the many calls to the server (the app is heavy in POST request/save
>   to db) is going to slow it down. Most importantly, it is an overkill
>
> SQLite seems to be the fastest. but it doesn't have the same power as MySQL or PostgreSQL (custom API route) for example.

So, where do I ask this question? And how can I edit it to suit a certain Stack Exchange site?

Comment: recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow. There's only one site that does recommendations and I hesitate to suggest it because you'd need a lot more information and I suspect they wouldn't go into performance of specific use cases, you'd need to do that yourself.

Comment: can you elaborate? I can adjust my question accordingly for the site. The question I am going to ask is actually very clear and just needs a professional judgement or someone who has tried the approaches really. By specific I meant that it is not something very broad like "best tool to learn java". It is more like "between sqlite, custom API and firebase, which is better for a schema with tables that contain lots of many-to-many tables. I care about speed"

Comment: Tell you what, do it the other way: include the question you want to ask in the question you're you're asking now. Folks will then be able to tell you whether it's on-topic somewhere, or if it might be but still needs work, with an estimation of said work. Or, as it can happen, if it's not suitable anywhere. In any way, it's best if we see you question before you post it; that's why it's called site-recommendation after all :)

Comment: Thank you! will do! :D

Comment: It's a good question, unfortunately just one that doesn't fit the Stack Exchange Q&A format very well.